# Customizing CreateUserWizardControl Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, createuserwizard

Quite baffled and **really** frustrated as to what is preventing a customization to the CreateUserWizardControl from recognizing the additional controls.  I am using VS 2012 and created the project from a asp.net Web Forms 4.5 template.  It is working when testing with VS 2012 on my development Windows 7 machine .  When I deploy using the VS File Publish feature from VS with no file exclusions and then xcopy to my IIS 8 web server.  I checked the deployed Register.aspx page and the controls are there; but, when I run the app the custom controls are not rendered to the page.  I looked at the view source, they are not there at all.  I have now simplified it down to just one checkbox and that is just not showing up.  It does not matter if I put it on the page outside the wizard entirely or in the content template, the layout template, or the fieldset--nothing works.

Have I missed a setting or a step somewhere?  My project is at a stand still for user testing and I am out of possibilities.

This is a code snippet:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" ID="RegisterUser" ViewStateMode="Disabled" 
        OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" 
        OnCreatingUser="RegisterUser_OnCreatingUser" 
        OnCreateUserError="RegisterUser_OnCreateUserError" 
         >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="navigationPlaceholder" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidLicenseNumber" runat="server" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" ID="RegisterUserWizardStep">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
                </p>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
                    <ol>
                        .....
                        Bunch of list items here from the template for 
                         user name, question, and password 
                        .....
                        <li>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="AgreeToTermsOfUse" runat="server" Text="Agree to Terms of Use"  />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Register" />
                </fieldset>
                 <p class="message-info">
                    Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%: Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %>characters in length. </p></ContentTemplate><CustomNavigationTemplate />
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by creating a completely new project and pulling in the existing pages minus the Wizard page.